# Print Whole List With Common Element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print the whole list (not just one item) if it includes Sydney and I am unsure what code I need to complete this.

```
car1 = ["Sydney", "CM11CAR", "Ford", "Fiesta", "Red", "3000", "1500", "3"]
car2 = ["Auckland", "CM22CAR", "Vauxhall", "Corsa", "Grey", "3100", "1550", "5"]
car3 = ["Brisbane", "CM33CAR", "Ford", "Focus", "Blue", "3100", "1550", "5"]

van1 = ["Brisbane", "CM11VAN", "Renault", "Master", "Green", "2900", "1450", "1500kg"]
van2 = ["Auckland", "CM22VAN", "Vauxhall", "Vivaro", "Blue", "3000", "1500", "2000kg"]
van3 = ["Perth", "CM33VAN", "Renault", "Traifc", "Red", "3100", "1550", "1500kg"]

minibus1 = ["Sydney", "CM11BUS", "Volkswagen", "Transporter", "Green", "3000", "1500", "5"]
minibus2 = ["Auckland", "CM22BUS", "Mercedes-Benz", "Sprinter", "Grey", "3100", "1550", "7"]
minibus3 = ["Perth", "CM33BUS", "Volkswagen", "California", "Blue", "3100", "1550", "5"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add an array holding all the other lists. Then, the program would if each of the vehicle lists has a value of "Sydney" using the `item in list` search. In the end, the last two lines of the code would print out the whole list as you've mentioned.

```
car1 = ["Sydney", "CM11CAR", "Ford", "Fiesta", "Red", "3000", "1500", "3"]
car2 = ["Auckland", "CM22CAR", "Vauxhall", "Corsa", "Grey", "3100", "1550", "5"]
car3 = ["Brisbane", "CM33CAR", "Ford", "Focus", "Blue", "3100", "1550", "5"]
lst = [car1, car2, car3]

for i in lst:
    for information in i:
        if "Sydney" in information:
            for x in range(len(i)):
                print(i[x])
```

Comment: To comment, TechDash's code is more efficient if you are going to standardize all the lists by having the city's name in the first index for every vehicle. If not, then just proceed.

Comment: You should just check using `if "Sidney" in i`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put all your lists into one list.
Like this:

```
vehicles = [car1, car2, car3, van1, van2, van3, minibus1, minibus2, minibus3]
```

Then loop over all the lists in `vehicles` and check the first element of that list which is a city and print the output.
Like this:

```
for vehicle in vehicles:
    if vehicle[0] == 'Sydney':
        print(vehicle)
```

Comment: Would `if 'Sydney' in vehicle:` be less performant?

Comment: As far as I know it won't make that much difference.